# How to retrieve UserDetails with Spring Security 3?

Tags: spring, security

```
www.someurl.com - public access not intercepted by Spring Security 3.
www.someurl.com/admin  - intercepted by Spring Security 3. Works fine.
```

I log into a page under www.someurl.com/admin. Then I change the url to www.someurl.com in the same window tab. I am working within the same http session so I expect to be able to retrieve user login details.

The public url request is handled by a dedicated controller. Within this controller, I have a wired user service. The implementer of this service is attempting to retrieve credentials but can't - Authentication object is null.

```
Authentication a=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
userDetails=(UserDetails) a.getPrincipal();
```

**=== UPDATE =========================**

When I inspect the HttpSession in the public url request controller, I see this attribute:

{SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ed20eaf7: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ed20eaf7: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ADMINISTRATOR,AUTHOR,EDITOR,READER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@380f4: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 43A582157C5813018632ACDD7499CF7D; Granted Authorities: ADMINISTRATOR, AUTHOR, EDITOR, READER}

Comment: The code looks okay - are you sure that you have spring security configured to intercept the www.someurl.com url?

Comment: Public urls are not intercepted. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes.  I'll put an answer together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get security details like you are, Spring Security must intercept the url, otherwise there won't be any security information.  You can add the following to your spring security config:

```
<security:http pattern="/" security='none' />
```

This means that spring security will let everyone see the root url (whether logged in or not), but spring security will process the url, meaning your controller against the root url will be able to get the current user login details from `SecurityContextHolder`

Comment: I already have this configuration `<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/admin/denied">`. Adding pattern and security as suggested above, causes me problems. Both public and admin pages stop loading for some reason. I don't want to play with interception more because my public urls are dynamic and I don't want to use anything like /** as that may affect security of /admin urls. For now, I'll get the Authentication attribute directly from session. At least I know what's going on and when I switch to Shiro, I'll do this properly.

Comment: BTW: I'm accepting because I got my question answered. Thanks.

Comment: @jacekn Put the /** rule at the end of all your other rules and it won't interfere with the ones that come before it - it works well in projects I've don before.